# How to identify duplicate keys when parsing a json object with json-cpp?

Tags: json, jsoncpp

I am trying to parse a json object read from a file.
I want to identify duplicate keys, as json-cpp doesn't like them (even if they are not illegal in json).

I need to be able to say: ERROR: your json file has duplicate keys and we dont like that.

```
Json::Reader reader(Json::Features::strictMode());
```

Using reader in strictMode does not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
rejectDupKeys
```

in

```
void Json::CharReaderBuilder::setDefaults   (   Json::Value *   settings    )
```

[JsonCPP Doc](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_char_reader_builder.html#ac69b7911ad64c171c51ebaf2ea26d958)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way out of the box, but you can program that functionality.
Since `JsonCPP` uses a map to store object keys, you have to add some code to:

```
Value &Value::resolveReference(const char *key, bool isStatic)
```

First, you have to be sure you are parsing (and not accessing some Json::Value). Then, you have to add something (like an exception or a flag) to this `if`:

```
if (it != value_.map_->end() && (*it).first == actualKey)
{
    // key is already present: if parsing, throw!
    return (*it).second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Open an issue](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/new). That could be added easily. (Sga's idea might be the best way.) We've done a lot of work recently to make it easier to add features while maintaining binary-compatibility.